# android.widget.Swtich - Keep state on pause?

Tags: java, android

I am a new developer writing an app that logs location when a switch is toggled. My switch works when I toggle it, but it loses it's state when I take the app out of the forefront. How do I keep the state of my android switch onPause and onResume?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        // set view, initiate switch
        Switch mainSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mainSwitch);

        // deal with switch
        mainSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                // if switch is on
                if (isChecked) {
                        logLocation();
                    }
                } else if (!isChecked) {
                    stopLocation();
                }
                // true if the switch is in the On position
                Log.v("@@@@@@@@@@@@@=", "" + isChecked);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Unless `onCreate` is called every time you return to the `Activity` the current checked state should still be there. Do you just press the home button or do you press the back button so you leave the app or?
If Android decides that your `Activity` isn't worth having in memory it will kick it out of memory and release all state.
Have a look at the `Activity` lifecycle here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java to get a better understanding of state is handled.
Let me know if it helps or if you need some more example code.

Comment: I lose the state when I press the back button, but the operations continue if that makes any sense (the switch gets unswitched, but the operations don't stop). As it's written, will the switch still be monitored if mainSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener is inside on onCreate? If I move this outside mainSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener I run into issues! Any advice would be so helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, when you click the back button the `Activity` is killed as `onDestroy` is called and so all state is also removed. Have a look at the link I provided in the first comment and look at the lifecycle and how you can save state. Also have a look at this documentation about different ways and reasons on how to save state: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: So after reading the first and second documents together, it seems like I need to save the current switch state onDestroy, and then reinitiate it somehow onRestoreInstanceState, is that correct? Offhand, do you know how to access the isChecked outside of the onCreate method? I also want to share this from my log when I click the back button on my log which I think might be important:

Comment: 2019-02-26 07:32:33.066 4691-4691/android.example.jasperwear E/ActivityThread: Activity android.example.jasperwear.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.example.jasperwear.MainActivity$3@bc865e5 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity android.example.jasperwear.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.example.jasperwear.MainActivity$3@bc865e5 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Comment: I've added an answer as I couldn't fit all the code and explanation into a comment ;-)
As far as your last question goes, I'd recommend you do open up a new question as to not clutter this question with something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer instead of continuing in the comments.

By default Android will save the state of your UI if and only if you're using default components (meaning `TextView`, `Button`, `Switch` etc.) and your component has an id. This state will only survive if the OS kills the app and the user returns to it. This means that if the user presses the `Home` button and then returns to your `Activity` at a later stage, the UI state of all default components of that specific `Activity` will be restored. When pressing the `Home` button the `Activity` is stopped and `onSaveInstanceState` is called, so here you get a chance to save any state that isn't maintained by default components or if you have some data you downloaded for instance that is used to populate your UI components with data.

If the user presses the `Back` button the app will be killed and any UI state won't be restored per default.
To overcome this, you can use `SharedPreferences` or any other local storage mechanism to store your UI state to disk basically.

I've added a snippet of code, that shows how you can use the different approaches.

In your case you don't need the `onSaveInstanceState` method implementation, as you have a default UI component, that knows how to save its own state already and as mentioned Android does this automagically for you already.

Both states (`savedInstanceState` and what goes into the `SharedPreferences`) should be restored in the `onCreate` method as this is always called whenever an `Activity` is re-created or created the first time, while `onRestoreInstanceState` might not be called all the time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private static final String CHECKBOX__STATE = "CHECKBOX__SAVE_STATE";

    private Switch checkbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkbox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        final boolean isChecked;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            isChecked = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CHECKBOX__STATE);
        } else {
            isChecked = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                    .getBoolean(CHECKBOX__STATE, false);
        }

        // Setting the state (if any) of the Switch.
        checkbox.setChecked(isChecked);

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: isChecked = true - log location");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: isChecked = false - stop logging location");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(CHECKBOX__STATE, checkbox.isChecked());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .edit()
                .putBoolean(CHECKBOX__STATE, checkbox.isChecked())
                .apply();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps :-)